# How to add a keybind from controller javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am (still) working on my todo application. While I'm thinking about where to place the save button, I figured I would add a keybind to save too.

I added the key bind in my main class like this:

```
final KeyCombination keyComb1 = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S,
        KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyComb1.match(event)) {

        }
    }
});
```

However, the stuff I need to do on the CRL + S is in the controller class. How can I bridge this or make it so the controller can get this information?

Edit: I do not want to pass any info. Just the fact that the event happened.

Edit 2.0: 
I have solved the issue. The solution was to get the controller instance at the start, save it and when the event was called, use the said method.

Comment: Call the controller class from the listener?

Comment: This is the main class where the scene is ini'd. How could I call the controller class from there?

Comment: Inside the listener, write something like this: ControllerClass.saveDataMethod(); (obviously replace each with their actual names)

Comment: Like a static inside the contoller?

Comment: Yeah, that would be optimal

Comment: Why would you make it `static`? That makes no sense: you wouldn't be able to access any of the UI controls from a static method. Just get a reference to the controller *instance* and call the method from the event handler.